# HOW TO CONVERT ONE DATE FORMAT TO ANOTHER IN A COLUMN IN EMEDITOR

Tags: emeditor

I have a File in Emeditor with date column with "December 30, 2021" & "2021-12-30" formats and i want to convert the entire column to "dd/mm/yyyy". How do i convert the entire column to my preferred format? Can you create a Macro for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure to update **EmEditor** version to the latest version including beta versions (**v21.5.905** or later).

1. Select a column you want to normalize dates.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the **Replace** dialog box.
3. Click **Number Range** to bring up the **Enter Number Range** dialog box.
4. Click **Date/times**, clear **Use default date format** check box, and enter `yyyy-MM-dd|yyyy-M-d|MMMM dd, yyyy|MMMM d, yyyy` below the check box. These are the date formats you want to search for, combined with a pipe (`|`).
5. Enter appropriate dates in **Minimum number** and **Maximum number** (optional), and click **OK**.

[image: Enter Number Range]

6. In the Replace dialog box, make sure the **In the Selection Only** option is set.
7. Enter `\D dd/MM/yyyy` in the **Replace with** box. This is a resultant date format.
8. Click **Replace All**.

[image: Replace]

If you prefer macros, you can write and run a macro like this:

```
document.selection.Replace("[1900-01-01 , 2100-12-31 \"yyyy-MM-dd|yyyy-M-d|MMMM dd, yyyy|MMMM d, yyyy\" ]","\\Ddd/MM/yyyy",eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll,eeExFindNumberRange);
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `NormalizeDate.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run NormalizeDate.jsee** in the **Macros** menu. You must select a column before you run this macro.

**References:**

- [Number Range Expression Syntax](http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_number_range_syntax.html)
- [EmEditor v21.6 beta](https://www.emeditor.com/forums/topic/emeditor-v21-6-beta-21-5-901/)

**Updates**

As of v21.5.906 or later, please remove a space after `/D`.

Comment: Hello Yutaka....I tried both the manual way & the macro but it keeps giving me this result " \D dd/MM/yyyy" on the entire Column

Comment: Are you using v21.5.905?

Comment: Did not update to the beta versions. After updating it works now. Thank you.